# Unresolved Reference In Python Method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find a reason to this Error. The Code Is

```
def x():
    if b == 1:
        a = a + 4
        print(a)
a = 5
b = 1 

x()
```

The second time my variable `a` is used : `a = a + 4`, an error occur.

I am developing a program which mainly uses this type of assignments.

Comment: you're assigning `a` and `b` outside the function scope. Basically, `x()` won't know their value at runtime. You should pass them as arguments.

Comment: But It Works For Other Variables in My Main Code

Comment: It should not. That code is simply wrong.

Comment: Edit your answer and provide a code sample where it works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The assignment `a = a + 4` tells the interpreter to use a local version of `a` instead of the global reference.

Now in the assignment `a = a + 4`, when the interpreter is looking up the value of the local variable `a`, the interpreter finds the variable to be undefined and will yield `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`.

You can change this behavior by using the `global` keyword:

```
def x():
    global a
    if b == 1:
        a = a + 4
        print(a)
        return
a = 5
b = 1
x()
```

---

**Q:** Hold on, why isn't the interpreter complaining about `b`?

**A:** Because you're not *assigning* anything to **b** within the function, thus the interpreter will use the variable `b` from the global scope.

However, global variables are not needed for this case. A more elegant version that avoids global variables would be:

```
def x(a, b):
    if b == 1:
        a = a + 4
    return a
print( x(5, 1) )
```

Note that this function behaves slightly differently. Your original function did not return anything, while my reworked version of `x` will always return the value of `a`, either modified or unmodified, depending on the value of `b`.

This has the advantage that you can work with the returned value and you can move the `print()` out of the function.

Comment: This is a solution to his problem but since OP is new I'd add a note to warned him about using globals. Especially in a code where his variables are not named correctly. That could lead to unwanted behavior.

Comment: If I Add Global "It Says Local variable 'healthp' might be referenced before assignment" Edit: Not 'healthp'. That Is From My Main Code

Comment: And the warning is correct. Avoid global variables if possble, there's an example in my answer. Btw, your code does not contain a variable named ``healthp``, so I will assume you're talking about ``a``.

Comment: Yes. You Are Right