# Closure within a function

Tags: python-3.x, closures

Within the scope of a function, I want to define and execute a closure which captures variables which exist only within the scope of the "outer" function.

I have found through experimentation that if assigning to a captured variable, it doesn't work by default: the line `i+=1` looks for a local `i` when assigning.  However the [usual solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50909299/2883198) — which would work without the wrapping "outer" function — doesn't work here:

```py
def outer():
    i = 1
    n = 10
    def inner():
        global i, n
        i += 1
        return i == n
    while not inner():
        pass
    print("done")
outer()
# NameError: name 'i' is not defined
# (on the line `i += 1`)
```

I know I could pass the captured variables as arguments to `inner` instead, but for my real case `inner` will be passed as data and executed elsewhere (within `outer`), so I'd ideally not want to have to `partial` it: closures seem a natural fit.

Is there a clean, clear way I can make this work in Python? Bonus points if there is a way I can make this work without typing `global`, which always makes me feel uneasy.

Comment: `global` doesn't work here because the scope you are attempting to access is not `global`. It's `nonlocal`. That being said, `partial` or `lambda` is probably a better solution. But it's hard to say without knowing the specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nonlocal` instead of `global`.

```py
def outer():
    i = 1
    n = 10
    def inner():
        nonlocal i
        i += 1
        return i == n
    while not inner():
        pass
    print("done")
outer()
# done
```

Thanks to [Axe319](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12479639/axe319) in the comments.